# Handling custom domain e-mails for multiple people

Tags: domains, email, email-address, email-accounts

I was using OVH custom domain to create custom mailboxes. Earlier this service had no additional pricing for hosting (you could create free 5MB hosting with up to 5 mailboxes). Now they changed the policy and hosting is very expensive (it is only for mailboxes). I wanted to work it around by leaving my custom domain/email (because I use it everywhere).

I thought about moving to Apple as they allow email aliases. The problem is I have multiple emails on this domain and those emails are not mine (one is my wife's, another my brother's, etc.). Is it possible to create alias on separate accounts, or the only way is redirecting emails? Perhaps, there is another way of solving the problem?

**[edit]**
In short, I want to achieve this:

- `user1@example.com` to be sent to `user1@icloud.com` (or other free mail)
- `user2@example.com` to be sent to `user2@icloud.com`

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve with the other emails?  Do you want them forwarded to a new address or keep the addresses with a mailbox?

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: Generally doing a forwarder for any mail address is a trivial task, it is in cpanel.  Don't set up a mailbox, just make a forwarder.  Make one for each address. If OVH doesn't have cpanel, you are going to have to contact their tech support.